# How to access variables and functions from different classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, functional-programming

I am just getting started with python. I got a Udemy course. I am trying to create a GUI application with the help of the `Tkinter` module but I stuck on one point and I have no clue how to do this.
I want to use `self.Email_Id` from `Login class` to `Main_Window class`. and I want to reuse the `MainLoop function` from `Login class` to `Main_Window class`. Otherwise, I have to rewrite that function which is not the convention according to code reusability.

And if possible please suggest, what can be the different ways to do that or work on multi-level windows. Below is my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk # For resizing Images
import sqlite3
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics # For getting screen resolution

Title_Font = ("roboto", 30, "bold")
Label_Font = ("roboto", 17, "bold")
Entry_Font = ("roboto", 14)
Button_Font = ("roboto", 20, "bold")

#------------------------------------------- Resizing Background Image to fit in window -------------------------------------------#
BG_Image = Image.open("Image/BG_Image.jpg")
Resized_BG_Image = BG_Image.resize((GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)))
Resized_BG_Image.save("Image/BG_Image_Resized.jpg")
#------------------------------------------- Resizing Background Image to fit in window -------------------------------------------#

Space=(" "*(int(GetSystemMetrics(0))//7)) # Adding space befor window title to be displayed in center of window

class Login:
    def __init__(self, Login_Page = Tk()):

        self.Login_Page = Login_Page # Initializing login page

        self.Login_Page.title(Space+"COMPASS Referral Form")
        self.Login_Page.geometry(f"{GetSystemMetrics(0)}x{GetSystemMetrics(1)}+0+0")
        self.Login_Page.wm_iconbitmap('Image/Icon.ico')
        self.Login_Page.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.Exit_Function)

        self.BG_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Image/BG_Image_Resized.jpg")
        BG = Label(self.Login_Page, image=self.BG_Image).pack()

        #------------------------------------------- Login Frame Designer -------------------------------------------#
        Login_Frame = Frame(self.Login_Page, bg="white")
        Login_Frame.place(x=20, y=50, width=580, height=400)

        self.Email_Id = StringVar()
        self.Password = StringVar()

        Title = Label(Login_Frame, text="Login Here", font=Title_Font, bg="white", fg='#08A3D2').place(x=250, y=0)

        Email_Label = Label(Login_Frame, text="Username or Email Address", font=Label_Font, bg="white", fg='grey').place(x=100, y=100)
        Password_Label = Label(Login_Frame, text="Password", font=Label_Font, bg="white", fg='grey').place(x=100, y=190)

        Email_Entry= Entry(Login_Frame, textvariable=self.Email_Id, font=Entry_Font, bg="light grey").place(x=100, y=140, width=350, height=30)
        Password_Entry = Entry(Login_Frame, textvariable=self.Password, font=Entry_Font, bg="light grey", show="*").place(x=100, y=230, width=350, height=30)

        Login_Button = Button(Login_Frame, command=self.Login_Function, text="Login",  font=Button_Font, fg="white", bg="#B00857", cursor="hand2").place(x=100, y=300, width=150, height=40)
        Exit_Button = Button(Login_Frame, command=self.Exit_Function, text="Exit",  font=Button_Font, fg="white", bg="dark red", cursor="hand2").place(x=300, y=300, width=150, height=40)
        Forgot_Button = Button(Login_Frame, command=self.Forget_Password_Window,  text="Forgot Password?", font=Entry_Font, bg="white", fg="#B00857", bd=0, cursor="hand2").place(x=270, y=190)

    def Login_Function(self):
        if self.Email_Id.get()=="" or self.Password.get()=="":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields are required", parent=self.Login_Page)
        else:
            try:
                con = sqlite3.connect('Database/COMPASS_PRF.db')
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  Login_Authentication where Email_Id=? AND Password=?", (self.Email_Id.get(), self.Password.get()))
                row = cur.fetchone()
                if row ==None:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error","Invalid email or password", parent=self.Login_Page)
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Login Success","Welcome, You have successfully logged in.!!!")
                    self.Login_Page.destroy()
                    con.close()
            except Exception as es:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error Due to {str(es)}", parent=self.Login_Page)
            
    def Exit_Function(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?"):
            exit()

    def Forget_Password_Window(self):
        pass

    def MainLoop(self):
        self.Login_Page.mainloop()

Login_Window = Login()
Login_Window.MainLoop()

class Main(Login):
    def __init__(self, Main_Window=Tk()):

        self.Main_Window = Main_Window
        self.Main_Window.title(Space+"Referral Form - Main Window")
        self.Main_Window.geometry(f"{GetSystemMetrics(0)}x{GetSystemMetrics(1)}+0+0")
        self.Main_Window.wm_iconbitmap('Image/Icon.ico')
        # self.Main_Window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.Exit_Function)

        # BG = Label(self.Main_Window, text=f"{Login.Email_Id.get()}").pack()

    def MainLoop(self):
        self.Main_Window.mainloop()

Main_Window = Main()
Main_Window.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `Main` should not inherited from `Login`.  Actually you can get the email by `Login_Window.Email_Id.get()` after `Login_Window` is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your variable because `Main` is a `Child` from `Login`. The `MainLoop` function should have a window input and then you can also access the `Mainloop` in `class Main` (A `Child` has all the `functions` from the `parent`). [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp) you can learn more about `Parent and Child classes` I hope I've answered your question